# Anova types R: which to use

Tags: r, anova

I would like to perform an ANOVA analysis to determine which factors can explain most of the variance for a response variable

```
y ~ A + B + A:B + C
```

My data are not balanced and I am totally confused on which type of anova should I use.

1) If I use Type I (aov) I get different results depending on the order (as expected)

2) I have been reading that Type II do not include the interaction.. However, I used the Anova (car) function with the type II specification and one of the analysed factor is A:B. What then does "not including the interaction" mean?

3) I have been reading that Type III shouldn't be used but I haven't really understood why..

Many thanks

Comment: You could also try fitting a regression model. No requirement for balanced data there.